# jQuery Validate plugin with Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I've been looking online and following various tutorials but I can't seem to get this to work. I'm trying to get my Ajax form to validate using the validate plugin.

Both codes work separately but after researching online and attempting to combine them using the `submitHandler` I haven't had much luck.

Here's my code, I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript so unless there is a tutorial for exactly what I want I struggle to combine previous lessons. It's a big contact form but all I really want to validate is the name, email and message type fields.

Thanks

James

```
 $('#arckocontact').validate({
 rules:{
     name: {
        required:true 
     },
     email: {
        required:true,
        email: true 
     }
 },// end rules
 messages:{
    name: {
        required: 'You must enter your name.',  
    },
    email: {
        required: 'You must supply an email address.',
        email: 'You must enter a valid email address.', 
    }
 }, //end messages
submitHandler: function(){  

var name = $("input#name").val();
var email = $("input#email").val();
var phone = $("input#phone").val();

var messagetype = $("input[name='messagetype']:checked").val();

var trackurl = $("input#trackurl").val();
var trackdesc = $("#trackdesc").val();

var eventdate = $("input#eventdate").val();
var eventdesc = $("#eventdesc").val();
var adrsone = $("input#adrsone").val();
var adrstwo = $("input#adrstwo").val();
var adrsthree = $("input#adrsthree").val();
var pcode = $("input#pcode").val();

var detail = $("input#subject").val();
var note = $("#note").val();

var stringone = 'Thank you, ';
var stringtwo = ' for contacting Arcko Digital, we will be in touch soon.';

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "processmail.php",
data: {'name': name, 
    'email': email,
    'phone': phone,
    'messagetype': messagetype,
    'trackurl': trackurl,
    'trackdesc': trackdesc,
    'eventdate': eventdate,
    'eventdesc': eventdesc,
    'adrsone': adrsone,
    'adrstwo': adrstwo,
    'adrsthree': adrsthree,
    'pcode': pcode,
    'detail': detail,
    'note': note},
 success: function() {
$('#form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
$('#message').html("<h2>Message Submitted.</h2>")
.append(stringone, name ,stringtwo)
.hide()
.fadeIn(1500);
}
});
return false;

}   //end form ajax

});// end validate()
```

Comment: Does your form include an input control of type submit?

Comment: A standard submit button, form is set to `method='post'` with no action. The Ajax code worked fine until I started adding the validation code and getting it to work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the scope of variable error.Add the variables inside ajax success function,

```
var stringone = 'Thank you, ';
var stringtwo = ' for contacting Arcko Digital, we will be in touch soon.';
var name = $("input#name").val();
```

Make sure try find the error in developer(Browser) console

Try this,

```
    $('#arckocontact').validate({
     rules:{
         name: {
            required:true 
         },
         email: {
            required:true,
            email: true 
         }
     },// end rules
     messages:{
        name: {
            required: 'You must enter your name.',  
        },
        email: {
            required: 'You must supply an email address.',
            email: 'You must enter a valid email address.', 
        }
     }, //end messages
    submitHandler: function(){  

    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();

    var messagetype = $("input[name='messagetype']:checked").val();

    var trackurl = $("input#trackurl").val();
    var trackdesc = $("#trackdesc").val();

    var eventdate = $("input#eventdate").val();
    var eventdesc = $("#eventdesc").val();
    var adrsone = $("input#adrsone").val();
    var adrstwo = $("input#adrstwo").val();
    var adrsthree = $("input#adrsthree").val();
    var pcode = $("input#pcode").val();

    var detail = $("input#subject").val();
    var note = $("#note").val();

    var stringone = 'Thank you, ';
    var stringtwo = ' for contacting Arcko Digital, we will be in touch soon.';

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processmail.php",
    data: {'name': name, 
        'email': email,
        'phone': phone,
        'messagetype': messagetype,
        'trackurl': trackurl,
        'trackdesc': trackdesc,
        'eventdate': eventdate,
        'eventdesc': eventdesc,
        'adrsone': adrsone,
        'adrstwo': adrstwo,
        'adrsthree': adrsthree,
        'pcode': pcode,
        'detail': detail,
        'note': note},
     success: function() {
**//Here my change** 
var stringone = 'Thank you, ';
var stringtwo = ' for contacting Arcko Digital, we will be in touch soon.';
var name = $("input#name").val();
    $('#form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Message Submitted.</h2>")
    .append(stringone, name ,stringtwo)
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500);
    }
    });
    return false;

    }   //end form ajax

    });// end validate()
```

Comment: Excellent, reviewed correctly and all is working fine now. Thanks